# Kotlin - Throw Custom Exception

Tags: exception, kotlin

How can I throw a custom exception in Kotlin? I didn't really get that much off the docs...

In the docs, it gets described what each exception needs, but how exactly do I implement it?

Comment: I guess the official guide https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/exceptions.html describes it very well. Or do I get you wrong?

Comment: well, got it now...

Answer (score 131, accepted):

One thing to keep in mind: if you are using the IntelliJ IDE, just a simple copy/paste of Java code can convert it to Kotlin.

Coming to your question, now. If you want to create a custom Exception, just extend Exception class like:

```
class TestException(message:String): Exception(message)
```

and throw it like:

```
throw TestException("Hey, I am testing it")
```

Comment: You've forgotten to pass your message to Exception constructor :)

Comment: I found that you only need to add the override keyword before var :)

Comment: @AlexanderRomanov `Exception` class has an empty constructor. But yes its good to pass message to base class if it is supporting that.

Comment: Of course it has, but in your case the "i am testing" message won't be shown.

Comment: @AlexanderRomanov yes you are right, but it was just for hint. Any way i will update answer. Thanks

Comment: Why not val message instead of var? There is no reason for the param to be mutable.

Comment: Why do we need to override the message here?

Comment: @Deepak Yes we do not need it, removed it. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: @chandil03 If I try to re-throw the custom exception again, compiler complaining about it not being a 'Throwable' ? 

ie throw error  (where error is TestException passed from a function)

Comment: @ArdenDev Did you extend it with Exception or Throwable?

Comment: I don't understand why you can't just use Exception("my message") in Kotlin? Isn't all of this custom class stuff overkill? It seems like kotlin provide a way to do it without needing custom class.

Comment: @mairs8 throwing `Exception` is a terrible UX for anyone using your library. They then can not catch your specific TestException, but need to instead catch all Exceptions. Please do not do it. `catch (TestException e) {}` is good code. `catch (Exception e) {}` is inadvisable and even your IDE will tell you you are wrong.

Answer (score 81):

Most of these answers just ignore the fact that Exception has 4 constructors.
If you want to be able to use it in all cases where a normal exception works do:

```
class CustomException : Exception {
    constructor() : super()
    constructor(message: String) : super(message)
    constructor(message: String, cause: Throwable) : super(message, cause)
    constructor(cause: Throwable) : super(cause)
}
```

this overwrites all 4 constructors and just passes the arguments along.

EDIT: Please scroll down to `R. Agnese` answer, it manages to do this without overriding 4 constructors which is error prone.

Comment: This answer should probably be ranked higher up. I've had **exactly** this use case in my code, and you were a lifesaver.

Comment: I needed t change the type `Throwable` to `Exception` than this answer was really helpful.

Comment: @loaded02 sorry could you elaborate? In what case do you need a throwable where an exception doesn't work? Exception extends Throwable, so any Exception can be a Throwable

Comment: @DownloadPizza you are right. Change not necessary.

Comment: It's annoying this boilerplate can't just be inherited/delegated somehow - if no constructors were specified, it would adopt all the superclass constructors.

Comment: @TimBaverstock check out R. Agnese answer below, way less boilerplate

Comment: In this how to throw exception with msg?

Comment: @UpendraShah If you just want an exception with a message just do `throw Exception("your message")`. This is for when you want people to catch your exceptions specifically in a trycatch

Answer (score 38):

I know this is old, but I would like to elaborate on @DownloadPizza's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64818325/9699180

You don't actually need four constructors. You only need two to match the base Exception class's four:

```
class CustomException(message: String? = null, cause: Throwable? = null) : Exception(message, cause) {
    constructor(cause: Throwable) : this(null, cause)
}
```

The Exception base class comes from the Java standard library, and Java doesn't have default parameters, so the Java class must have four constructors for every combination of acceptable inputs. Furthermore, both `message` and `cause` are allowed to be `null` in Exception, so ours should be, too, if we're trying to be 100% compatible with Exception.

The only reason we even *need* the second constructor is to avoid needing to use named argument syntax in Kotlin code: `CustomException(cause = fooThrowable)` vs `Exception(fooThrowable)`.

Comment: Very good, mentioned you in an edit. This is abuse of default args and I like it

Answer (score 22):

Like this:

### Implementation

```
class CustomException(message: String) : Exception(message)
```

### Usage

```
 fun main(args: Array<String>) {
     throw CustomException("Error!")            // >>> Exception in thread "main"
 }                                              // >>> CustomException: Error!
```

*For more info: [Exceptions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/exceptions.html)*

Answer (score 0):

### Why not merge both answers

Suppose you want to throw a custom Exception in the Calculator. Logging is optional you can remove the init block

```
class CalculationException constructor(message: String= "ERROR: Invalid Input", cause: Throwable): Exception(message, cause) {
    init {
        Log.e("CalculationException", message, cause)
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

No Message

```
    throw(CalculationException())
```

**Output**: Default Message

> Caused by: CalculationException: ERROR: Invalid Input

---

OR

Only message no cause

```
    throw(CalculationException("Some Weird Exception"))
enter code here
```

**Output**: Custom Message

> Process:  PID: 23345
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{CalculationException: Some Weird Exception

---

OR

Both message and Cause

```
    throw(CalculationException("Divide ByZero", ArithmeticException()))
```

> 2021-08-12 19:36:55.705 17411-17411/
> E/CalculationException: Divide ByZero
> java.lang.ArithmeticException

Answer (score 0):

Simplest/shortest solution, if you do not require anything else, is this

```
    class CustomException : Exception()
```