# How to throw exception in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

In Android Application using Room Database

Method in `DataManager` class

```
fun insertStudent(studentModel : StudentModel): Long{

   return studentDao.add(studentModel)
}
```

Method in my `ViewModel`

```
fun addStudentToDB(name : String, age : Int, level : String){
       StudentModel student = StudentModel(name,age,level);
       getDataManager().insertStudent(student);
}
```

calling View Model method from Activity/ Fragment if Room Database throw any Sql exception . How I am going to notify my activity to show any message or toast to user

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45162869/kotlin-throw-custom-exception

Comment: surround the throwing code with [try / catch](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/exceptions.html) to catch the exception and use it as you wish

Answer (score 0):

You can mark methods which can throw exceptions

```
@Throws(SQLException::class)
fun addStudentToDB(name : String, age : Int, level : String){
    StudentModel student = StudentModel(name,age,level);
    getDataManager().insertStudent(student);
}
```

Then use like this in activity

```
try {
    addStudentToDB()
} catch (e: SQLException) {
    //toast
}
```

Note: Kotlin doesn't force you to use try catch even if method throws an exception.

Comment: Then how to propagate exception to another function -- likewise in Activity/Fragment

Comment: Add @Throws to that function.

Comment: You don't need @Throws to propagate an exception or catch it. It is merely informative.